# Can a WKWebView call a function in the main app and get a value back?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am currently writing a web page that is designed to be run inside a WKWebView on iOS, or a WebView on Android. On Android, it is possible for the WebView to call a function that executes native app code and returns a value back to the WebView. Is it possible to do the same on iOS? Can I call a native iOS function and get a value returned back from it, in one way or another?

Comment: Stop. UIWebView has been deprecated for years. Use WKWebView. And yes, there is a way to call out from the html/javascript into your app.

Comment: @matt edited to ask about WKWebView instead. (I am not the iOS engineer, so I have no idea which WebView they are using.) Also, the most important part of the question is whether or not this communication is two-way.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly is possible, but needs a lot of preparation work.
I made this a few years ago https://github.com/ddaddy/DJJavaInsertion when I needed to be able to control how an app works by changing `JavaScript` on a webpage. It uses `UIWebView` but you should be able to modify it to use `WKWebView`

The way it works is it loads your web page and kicks off an initial js function. As your js needs to call an Obj-C method it makes an iframe call to a specially formulated url which the webview delegate catches and performs the function.

I used it to present native alerts, request data input and even perform quite complex web requests.

I doubt it’ll be a drop in for you, but may show you how to do it.